# c# - how to read / as a string?

Tags: c#

I have a `txtSerial.text = S/N123-122`.

When I use `txtSerial` as a path to save as excel file, It will save as a folder with name ended with `S` instead of `S/N123-122.xls` (not a folder).

Is there a way to make sure the program read `/` as full string and not as end of path?

Thanks

Comment: Filenames cannot contain slashes (either forward or back slashes), so no.

Comment: Well you'll need to change `/` to something else. That's a directory separator in every operating system I've used... you could potentially remove it entirely, or replace it with `_` or similar.

Comment: Forward slash characters aren't valid in file names - try and create one in Windows explorer yourself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A filename cannot contain any of the following characters: \ /:*?"<>|

Answer (score 5):

Windows doesn't allow `/` in file names, so you can't do that through C#. Try creating a file on your desktop with that name and you'll notice that it is not allowed!

One solution is to use another separator S-N for example.